# Alternative to using Variable in a View

Tags: mysql, variables, view, count, greatest-n-per-group

I need some assistance building a SQL statement that will output the top 5 retired assets per client that can be put into a SQL View.

I have built the following SQL statement but it will not work within a view and need an alternative.

```
SET @row_number := 0;

SELECT DISTINCT NAME, RetiredDate, COMMENT, 
  @row_number:=CASE WHEN @client_ID=clientID THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS num, 
  @client_ID:=clientID ClientID
FROM `retiredassets`
WHERE `retiredassets`.`ClientID` IN(SELECT clientID FROM `clients`)
HAVING num <=5
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? The above statement works flawlessly but cannot work within a SQL View.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: We are on MySQL 5.7 currently.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 this should be:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT r.NAME, r.RetiredDate, r.COMMENT,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.ClientID ORDER BY ...) AS num,
      r.ClientID
    FROM retiredassets
    JOIN clients USING (ClientID)
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE num <= 5;
```

I left `...` because I don't know what your ordering is. Your original query doesn't specify an order, so you'll have to choose one.

---

Re your comment.

If you can't upgrade to MySQL 8.0, and you can't use variables in a VIEW definition, then you can't use a VIEW. You will have to write out the full query when you use it, until you can upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: We actually are using MySQL Server 5.7, so this will not work for my instance unfortunately. I actually attempted something like that and confirmed that command does not work.